# My form does not submit even when the validation is correct

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a form that checks if the email is valid and if it is valid then it will submit. I'm not sure but i think think it does not submit because i added .preventDefault, but if i do not use preventDefault the form will not check for validation and directly submit. I'm still learning how to use javascript, please help me correct my mistake. Thankyou

codepen : https://codepen.io/jerico001/pen/yLMZyWJ

```
HTML
<form id="form" class="form" novalidate>
            <div class="form-control">
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email address"
                id="email"
                class="email"
                name="email"
              />
              <small></small>
              <button class="submit">Request Access</button>
            </div>
          </form>

JS
 const form = document.getElementById("form");
      const email = document.getElementById("email");
      const regx =
        /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

      form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        checkInputs();
      });

      function checkInputs() {
        const emailValue = email.value.trim();

        if (emailValue.match(regx)) {
          setSuccessFor(email);
        } else {
          setErrorFor(email, "Looks like this is not an email");
        }
      }

      function setErrorFor(input, message) {
        const formControl = input.parentElement;
        const small = formControl.querySelector("small");

        formControl.className = "form-control error";
        small.innerText = message;
      }

      function setSuccessFor(input) {
        const formControl = input.parentElement;
        formControl.className = "form-control success";
      }
```

Comment: I can't see where your submitting the form

Comment: You could do via the attribute required and the pseudo class :valid  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XWMObeE (without javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the event listener on the wrong thing and it's preventing the eventual submission. Put the event on the submit button and make that button type='submit'

```
<button type="submit" class="submit">Request Access</button>
```

Then in your script, check for a true/false return from your validation function to decide whether or not to submit the form

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const btn = document.querySelector('button.submit'); 
btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (checkInputs()) form.submit()
  });

  function checkInputs() {
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    if (emailValue.match(regx)) {
      setSuccessFor(email);
      return true;
    } else {
      setErrorFor(email, "Looks like this is not an email");
      return false;
    }
  }
```